# Unity - unity error cs2001 source file could not be found 2018

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ever since i updated my Unity, It keep telling me

error cs2001 source file "Scripts.cs" could not be found

I even tried creating a whole new project with new file and still getting this problem.

Anybody knows how to fix this problem!!!!!!

Sorry for my English.

**Unity Version 2018.1.0f2**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKaYi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the missing file is a script that you've renamed or deleted, simply recreate a script with the same name in the location mentioned. Then let Unity recompiles the scripts. Once successfully compiled feel free to delete the file if it no longer is necessary.

Comment: This didn't help, it still wanted the old file

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into that same problem as well after restoring a Windows system restore point. I assume that Windows restored some old Unity cache files in that process which led to that error.

Simply creating the missing file(s) works. But if you did a lot of changes / renames / removals recently you may have to re-create quite a lot of files to make it compile again.

If you're using version control like Git or SVN you can jump back to an earlier point in your change history (one where the probelmatic files still existed), let Unity compile and then go back to your current state.

Answer (score -1):

Check the folow:

1 Location of your update files in linux have 777 permissions for the user you have?. Or your file is in the location?.
2 path to the file correct writely?. You know in Windows or Linux use / or \ test it
3 your file have a name with extension correctly?

I hope this helps